# blur event not firing on angular component

Tags: angular, components, custom-controls

I am trying to get a reactive form to properly handle blur events and it doesn't seem to react properly to blur.

```js
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-combo-box-basic',
  templateUrl: './combo-box-basic.html'
})
export class ComboBoxBasic {

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target']) onBlur(target) {
    console.log(`onBlur(): ${new Date()} - ${JSON.stringify(target)}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group mr-3">
  <input (blur)="onBlur($event.target)" type="text" class="btn btn-outline-success">
  <div class="btn-group" ngbDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
    <button (blur)="onBlur($event.target)" class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
      <button class="dropdown-item">One</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Two</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Four!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

After a lot of searching and experimentation I found a number of items that were needed to get it work properly. [A fully functional demo can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsu3sp)

1. The Outer element must have: `tabindex="0"` so that it is focusable. This is achieved with: `@HostBinding('attr.tabindex') tabindex = '0';`
2. Adding a HostListener for blur events will catch outer component: `@HostListener('blur', ['$event.target']) onBlur(target) { ... }`
3. You still need to catch the blur events for the inner components so that clicking in and out will still fire. `(blur)="onBlur($event.target)"`

```js
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-combo-box-basic',
  templateUrl: './combo-box-basic.html'
})
export class ComboBoxBasic {

  // Make sure container can receive focus or else blur events won't be seen.
  @HostBinding('attr.tabindex') tabindex = '0';
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target']) onBlur(target) {
    console.log(`onBlur(): ${new Date()} - ${JSON.stringify(target)}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group mr-3">
  <input (blur)="onBlur($event.target)" type="text" class="btn btn-outline-success">
  <div class="btn-group" ngbDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
    <button (blur)="onBlur($event.target)" class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
      <button class="dropdown-item">One</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Two</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Four!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**blur event does not fire on controls in formarray**

The same problem i.e. `blur` event not firing, and the same solution as suggested by [@ronnblack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81730/ronnblack), in a different situation albeit:
In my case, blur event was not firing under a `formarray`. blur event fired in development mode though, however in production build, blur event is not firing in `input` and `select`, did not check on others. Solution is the same, set `tabindex="0"` for containing `div` for formarray, and the event started firing. Just in case, if someone faces the same situation.

Comment: WHAT? Thank you so much for this comment. I would have never figured this out otherwise.